# Individual Customization For Clutter Feature

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

I understand Clutter is based off of individual patterns, but I want to whitelist email from a sender. For example, if an e-mail was sent to my Clutter folder, I want that specific e-mail not to go there anymore. Is there a setting for me to stop that single e-mail from going into that folder?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, but Clutter learns. Sooner or later it will stop sorting your important messages. You can find more details in the [Office Support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Clutter-to-sort-low-priority-messages-in-Outlook-7b50c5db-7704-4e55-8a1b-dfc7bf1eafa0).

Comment: @Abraxas: just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this - but not from the client mailbox.  Below I use subject but you can scope this to a sender, recipient, or any other property supported by the transport rules.

You have to create a transport rule to catch these messages, than add the following to the message header:

```
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-BypassClutter : true
```

So in Exchange Admin Center - add a new transport rule

[image]

Or If you wanted to do this in PowerShell it would look like this

```
New-TransportRule -Name "Bypass Clutter" -SubjectContainsWords "Vendor Invoice" -SetHeaderName "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-BypassClutter" -SetHeaderValue "true"
```

Anything with the subject of "Vendor Invoice" will not be processed by clutter